# QGIS style overwrites layer variable

Tags: pyqgis, style, qml, qgis-variable

I set a layer variable with `QgsExpressionContextUtils.setLayerVariable(layer, name, value)` and then apply a style which is using the value of this variable (a color).

But when applying the style with `layer.loadNamedStyle(style)` it erases the layer variable. I deleted XML custom properties in relation with variables :

```
<property key="variableNames"/>
<property key="variableValues"/>
```

in the QML file but the layer variables are always deleted when applying the style. Is there a way to keep them ? Maybe when I export the style of the layer in QML, uncheck some elements from the list of exported parameters ?